# undefined method with nested attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a Trial model, which creates treatment_selection and repetition on create.

With repetition I'm looking to save the trial_id and treatment_selection_id which i'm trying to do via a :through association.

When the Trial form is submitted I getting the following error:

```
undefined method `repetitions' for #<TreatmentSelection:0x007ff76b8c3830>
```

**Trial Controller**

```
def create
    @trial = Trial.new(trial_params)
    @trial.treatment_selections.build.repetitions.build
end

private
    def trial_params
        params.require(:trial).permit(:year, :cultivation_id, :region_id, :cooperator_id, :field_id, :property_id, treatment_selections_attributes: [TreatmentSelection.attribute_names.map(&:to_sym).push(:_destroy), repetitions_attributes: [:trial_id, :treatment_selection_id]])
  end
```

**Models**

```
class Trial < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :treatment_selections, dependent: :destroy

  has_many :repetitions, through: :treatment_selections, source: :treatment

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :repetitions, allow_destroy: true
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :treatment_selections, allow_destroy: true
end

class TreatmentSelection < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :trial
  belongs_to :treatment
end

class Repetition < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :treatment_selection
end
```

The treatment_selection model has a helper as follow, which the user can add dynamically.
**trials_helper**

```
module TrialsHelper
  def link_to_add_row(name, f, association, **args)
    new_object = f.object.send(association).klass.new
    id = new_object.object_id
    fields = f.fields_for(association, new_object, child_index: id) do |builder|
      render(association.to_s.singularize, f: builder)
    end
    link_to(name, '#', class: "add_fields " + args[:class], data: {id: id, fields: fields.gsub("\n", "")})
  end
end
```

**Schema**

```
 create_table "repetitions", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "trial_id"
    t.integer "treatment_selection_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end
```

**Log**

```
Started POST "/trials" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-10-22 14:45:57 +1000
Processing by TrialsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"I2QheHAPOuhnv61Ghs0UoVgXcbYvX73AA7+nI/JTvRU4lTRYJbOdCstuTt/i7/4H2dV6wv4Vdt6zcQ7oo1id6w==", "trial"=>{"year(2i)"=>"1", "year(3i)"=>"1", "year(1i)"=>"2018", "region_id"=>"3", "cooperator_id"=>"1", "property_id"=>"1", "field_id"=>"5", "cultivation_id"=>"1", "treatment_selections_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"treatment_id"=>"3", "ambassador"=>"0", "_destroy"=>"false"}, "1"=>{"treatment_id"=>"", "ambassador"=>"0", "_destroy"=>"false"}, "2"=>{"treatment_id"=>"", "ambassador"=>"0", "_destroy"=>"false"}}}, "commit"=>"Submit"}
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 65ms (ActiveRecord: 11.6ms)


NoMethodError (undefined method `repetitions' for #<TreatmentSelection:0x007ff76b8c3830>):

app/controllers/trials_controller.rb:48:in `block in create'
app/controllers/trials_controller.rb:47:in `times'
app/controllers/trials_controller.rb:47:in `create'
```

**Trial Form**

```
<%= form_with(model: trial, local: true) do |f| %>
    <%= f.date_select :year, {order: [:year] %>
    ... Other Trial fields...
    <%= f.fields_for :treatment_selections do |builder| %>
        <%= render 'treatment_selection', f: builder %>
    <% end %>

    <%= f.submit 'Submit' %>
<% end %>
```

**Treatment selection partial**

```
<%= f.collection_select :treatment_id, Treatment.order('name'), :id, :name %>
  <%= f.check_box :ambassador %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :_destroy, as: :hidden %>
  <%= link_to 'Delete', '#', class: "remove_treatment" %>
```

Comment: Where do you get that error? Please add the relevant code to the question

Comment: On Trial form submit. Added form code and log.

Comment: Can you also add `_treatment_selection.html.erb`?

Comment: Your code in `create` action `@trial.treatment_selections.build` will return a `TreatmentSelection` object which doesn't have a definition for `repetitions` as defined in its model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your assocations are not quite right.

In order to join Trial to Repetition you need to setup an association in TreatmentSelection to go through:

```
class TreatmentSelection < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :trial
  belongs_to :treatment
  has_many :repetitions, dependent: :destroy
end
```

This lets you properly go through this assocation:

```
class Trial < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :treatment_selections, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :repetitions, through: :treatment_selections
end
```

You are also using the `source` option improperly. Its used when you have to tell ActiveRecord which assocation on the join model corresponds to the desired model (when the names don't match).

You should also remove the `repetions.trial_id` column  as it creates an undesirable duplication.

You also need to add the assocations to repetitions that go back up the chain:

```
class Repetition < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :treatment_selection
  has_one :treatment, through: :treatment_selection
  has_one :trial, through: :treatment_selection
end
```

You also should setup the nested attributes as follows:

```
class Trial < ApplicationRecord
  # ...
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :treatment_selections, allow_destroy: true
end 

class TreatmentSelection < ApplicationRecord
  # ...
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :repetitions, allow_destroy: true
end
```

This is crucial since the attributes should be nested two levels.

```
{ 
   trial: {
     treatment_selection_attributes: [
        {
          treatment_id: 1,   
          repetition_attributes: [
            { foo: 'bar' }
          ]
        },
        {
          treatment_id: 1,   
          repetition_attributes: [
            { foo: 'bar' }
          ]
        }
     ]
   }
}
```

ActiveRecord does not understand that the nested attributes go through another assocation.

You also should nest the calls to fields_for.

```
<%= form_with(model: trial, local: true) do |f| %>
  <%= f.fields_for :treatment_selections do |tsf| %>
    <%= tsf.fields_for :repetitions do |rf| %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Doing nested fields two levels is kind of hard and I would start by writing some model tests/specs that test that creating a Trial with two levels of nested attributes creates both the TrialSelection and Repetition. This is very much a sanity test to ensure the assocations are correct and that you have setup the nested attributes correctly without getting the views mixed into the picture.

Comment: Thanks Max this is great stuff. I've made the updates as suggested by getting an **Repetitions is invalid** error. Think it's related to the @trial.repetitions.build in create.

Comment: Yeah, I’m not quite sure what you’re doing there. You need to actually save the records as well. If the form needs seeding you should do that if the save operation fails.

Comment: My treatment_selections are being build dynamically, so doing @ trial.repetitions.build doesn't seem to be working. If I do @ trial.treatment_selections.build.repetitions.build it doubles up on my treatment_selections build if that makes sense.

Comment: Accepted this are the right answer. Problem I'm having now is seperate. Thanks @Max.

Answer (score 2):

Your code in `create` action `@trial.treatment_selections.build` will return a `TreatmentSelection` object which doesn't have a definition for `repetitions` as defined in its model.

Maybe you mean:

```
@trial.treatment_selections.build
@trial.repetitions.build
```

Comment: @Pavan, I think these lines of code are unnecessary because he is using nested attributes. It should automatically build objects using `trial_params`. An additional of two more record will be created on `@trial.save`

Comment: Yes, thats true. He should just keep `@trial = Trial.new(trial_params)`

Answer (score 0):

you are building repetitions object on TreatmentSelection model which does not specify relationship between TreatmentSelection and Repetition model , 
you need to add has_many :repetitions in TreatmentSelection model to make this working.